# Need to delimit table of 8 columns into only 5

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got a big list of names separated by commas in varying columns anywhere from 5 to 10.

I need to sort all those so that it makes a nice table with only 5 columns, and adds the extra names down to the row below.

The order of the names has to stay the exact same.

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: A picture of current file and desired result would be very helpful in working out a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[8 columns or 10 columns? and it can help someone trying to answer if the likes of 'big' where a little less subjective. I have ignored the 'separate by commas' since I don't understand its relevance.]

Copy your data and Paste Special into Word as Unformatted Text, Select All, Replace All ^p with ^t then ^t^t with ^t until there are no more to replace, Convert Text to Table with Number of columns: 5 and paste into Excel.